# How can I fetch the last N entities in Javascript for a Azure storage table query

Tags: javascript, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I have the query code below, but it fetches the top 3 values with one of two primary keys. What I want is to select the last 3 rows instead.

FYI - my RowKeys are incramentally added numbers (ex. 1,2,3,4,5)

```
var tableUri = "https://mytableuri.table.core.windows.net"; 
    var tableService = AzureStorage.Table.createTableServiceWithSas(tableUri, sasToken);
    var tableQuery = new AzureStorage.Table.TableQuery().top(3).where('PartitionKey eq ? or PartitionKey eq ?', partitionA, partitionB);
```

I want something like

```
var tableQuery = new AzureStorage.Table.TableQuery().last(3).where('PartitionKey eq ? and RowKey starts at TotalCount or PartitionKey eq ? and RowKey starts at TotalCount', partitionA, partitionB);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve latest record using RowKey or Timestamp in Azure Table storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593939/how-to-retrieve-latest-record-using-rowkey-or-timestamp-in-azure-table-storage)

Answer (score 1):

I found this article useful
[How to retrieve latest record using RowKey on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593939/how-to-retrieve-latest-record-using-rowkey-or-timestamp-in-azure-table-storage)

So what I did, because the article has a time stamp as the row key, and I'm using an integer.

I set the first row key to a large number like 10000000 and then decremented with each entry...

As these entries represent chat messages between two people, that large number of 10 million will never be hit between two people.

Now I can just take the top(N) and that will be the latest messages between them...