# Azure Storage Table get latest row ADF

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have created a azure storage table and I need to get the last inserted row. I have tried using a filter with something like `@equals(int(formatDateTime(item().date,'yyMMddHHmmss')),max(int(formatDateTime(item().date,'yyMMddHHmmss'))))`
I am open to any ideas

Comment: Are you trying to get last inserted row from Adf pipeline?

Comment: I have a rest call then I copy that json data to an azure table storage and I need the last date inserted as a highwater mark

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying with ADF, kindly note that **max()** is not supported for azure table storage as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service) of Table Service Query Operators.

[image]

Two of the methods for getting the latest entry/row is using the date-time. For example, `DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`

This is not good practice if the order is random based on the rowkey.

Another approach is using the Timestamp:

```cs
results.OrderByDescending(r => r.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault();
```

Refer to the SO Thread [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212971/16630138) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40593939/16630138) for more information.

Comment: How do I achieve the Ticks way and set a variable within Azure pipelines and not in C#